# What are the differences between "lay" and "lie"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, lie-lay-lain-laid

I'm confused about *lay* and *lie*. Please look at these examples:

> "Don't lie in the sun for too long." 
>   "The dog was lying dead on the floor." 
>   "She lay back against the pillows." 
>   "I told her a lie about what I was doing."

What are differences between these sentences?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/105/what-is-the-difference-between-lay-and-lie

Comment: lie- Simple Present, lying- present continuous, lay- simple past

Comment: To add to the mess, there's also telling lies. "Don't *lie* about your income", "he *lied* in his tax form", "he was *lying* about his relationship with her the whole time". Don't ask me about the past participle :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *lie* yourself and you *lay* something  - the **very basic** thing.

For instance,

> You lie down on the floor **OVER** 
>  You lay a pot on the floor.

**This is about the present tense.**

I could not find anything better than simply putting GrammarGirl's excellent examples here, *in-situ*.

The past tense of lie is lay, so...

> Last week, Steve lay down on the floor. 
>   The cat lay in the mud after it rained yesterday.

The past tense of lay is laid, so

> Last week, I laid the TPS report on your desk.
>  Mary forcefully laid her ring on the table.

The past participle of lie is lain *(this is wonderful)*, so

> Steve has lain on the floor for days. 
>   The cat has lain in the mud for hours.

The past participle of lay is laid, so

> I have laid the TPS report on your desk.
>  Mary has forcefully laid her ring on the table.

Comment: How could I understand "lay" is the past form of "lie"?

Comment: I think it is hard to recognize them from each other.

Comment: Are they grammatically different?

Comment: @IceGirl [Lay vs Lie](http://www.chompchomp.com/handouts/irregularrules02.pdf)

Comment: @IceGirl correct. it's difficult. GrammarGirl agrees on that :O *Don't feel bad if you can't remember these right away. Practice will help, and truthfully, I still have to look them up every time I use them.*

Comment: @IceGirl *how could I understand *lay* is past form...* ~ Well, the **context** will help. Check the examples - the cat ... **yesterday**; **Last week** ...Steve lay down.

Comment: Note that if "to lie" is used to mean "to tell an untruth", then the past tense and past particle are both "lied".

Comment: The "something" you *lay* can be oneself, *you lay yourself down to sleep*.

Answer (score 1):

Something lies somewhere. You lay something somewhere. The sentence structures are totally different. But I admit these two verbs with their similar stem forms have their difficulty. There is only one means to remember the forms. Write down the stem forms occasionally.

- lie/lay/lain
- lay/laid/laid. Originally a regular verb, layed became laid.

Answer (score 1):

I love pictures in [You Tube video](https://www.vocabulary.cl/english/lay-lie-difference.htm). A picture thousand words!

[image]

[image]