# What's the difference between LAY and LIE?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-meaning, verbs, word-difference

This has been confusing for me.

Some say:

> **"I'm laying on/in my bed."**

Others say:

> **"I'm lying on/in my bed."**

Which is correct?
Do the sentences have any difference?

I'm not sure which preposition to use either.
Can **ON** and **IN** be used with these verbs?

Comment: This question has an answer [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23759/what-are-the-differences-between-lay-and-lie). Here's also an [interesting article](http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/051402lielay.htm) on lie vs lay.

Comment: It has? Thanks for the links. I'll check them out ASAP :)